# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Tags: python, pandas, flask

So I was creating an web app to visualize your whats-app messaging data and I used python to do this. But every-time I run the script it keeps giving me this error `AttributeError: 'str'` object has no attribute '`groupby'`

The thing is I is I am using pandas methods everywhere in the code and I not really sure if it's compatible with flask

```
def member_count(df):
    print(type(df))    
    df = df.groupby(sender_name)[content].nunique()
    print(type(df))
    return df.to_json(orient='index')
```

```py
@app.route('/analysis', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      file = request.files['file']
      file.save(secure_filename("data.json"))
      df = get_data()
      name = member_count(df)
      names = name.keys()
      count =  name.values()
      colour = ["#33C6FF","#4176B2"]
      return render_template('analysis.html',set=zip(count, names, colour))
```

```py
[evaluate Analyser.py]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
{"Abhinav Chaudhary":12937,"Nirushini Siva":14220}
```

> File
>   "C:\Users\Abhinav\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MessengerAnalyser\app.py",
>   line 24, in uploader_file
>       name = member_count(df)   File "C:\Users\Abhinav\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MessengerAnalyser\app.py",
>   line 105, in member_count
>       df1 = df.groupby('sender_name')['content'].nunique()

Comment: How is call function `member_count` ?

Comment: just updated it

Comment: Are you passing an actual dataframe into your function, or by chance are you passing a string variable in?

Comment: Yes I am passing in an actual data frame

Comment: what is your df? can you show us the output of type(df)?

Comment: this is the output for the member_count function                                        
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
{"Abhinav Chaudhary":12937,"Nirushini Siva":14220}

Comment: Ok, and how did you get this? {"Abhinav Chaudhary":12937,"Nirushini Siva":14220}? That does look like you have your json returned.

Comment: Yeah so if Run this on Python it works fine no errors. But as soon as I run the @app.route('/analysis', methods = ['GET', 'POST']), so flask. It gives me that error

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of get_data(). Bug somewhere in this function.